# Is Gintama ending or not?

Tags: manga-production, gintama

I came across this Kotaku article called ["Gintama Manga Isn't Ending Yet Because Its Creator Screwed Up"](https://kotaku.com/gintama-manga-isnt-ending-yet-because-its-creator-screw-1829051940), and I'm not really clear on what's going on.

So apparently, Gintama was originally going to end in *Weekly Jump* on September 15, 2018. But now it seems like it's not ending, and it's moving to *Jump Giga* instead? What happened there? Could someone explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mentioned [here](https://twitter.com/Kewl0210/status/1039984864571867137): [image]

Apparently, the author miscalculated in trying to estimate on when the series will end. He mentioned that in Jump, **mangaka have to notify the editorial department 6 months in advance before the date that the manga is expected to end**.

However, he seemed to have realized after informing the editorial department that he could not fit everything he needed for a proper ending in the remaining chapters. Since informing the editorial department of the projected ending is probably absolute, meaning **he can't take back what he said on the predicted date that it will end** and **there is most likely another manga that was already scheduled to replace Gintama in Weekly Jump** since he already informed them that he will end the manga, it was transferred to Jump Giga from Weekly Jump.

**Is Gintama ending or not?** Based on this information, no, it's not yet ending.